# Exception in Apache StringUtils

Tags: java, string, jsp, apache-stringutils

hello guys i am try to use the StringUtils.remove Method but the below exception is raising i have include the jar file and StringUtils.lowercase and String.countsMatches is working only remove is not what may be the problem

```
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils"%>
```

this is how i imported and the exception is as follows

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.remove(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)
Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: which version of commons-lang are you using?
Did you check if the method exists with same parameters in that version?!

Comment: The `remove(String,String)` method was added to version 2.1 of commons-lang. It is not present in 2.0 and earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `remove(String,String)` method was added to version 2.1 of commons-lang. It is not present in 2.0 and earlier.

Depending on which Servlet Container or Application Server you use (and which version of it), the server class path may contain an outdated version of commons-lang, which is used instead of your copy of commons-lang in the applications /lib folder. If that's your problem, you can configure your application to prefer the application class path, instead of the server class path.

Comment: yes right !! The remove(String,String) method was added to version 2.1, it saved my time..

Answer (score 0):

Because as far as I can see in javadoc StringUtils has method remove that accepts 2 string arguments and does not have one that accepts 3 arguments:

```
public static String remove(String str,
                            String remove)
```

see http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Since there are different versions of StringUtils double check that your are working with the same version in development and deployment environment.

Comment: The last `String` in the signature `(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)
Ljava/lang/String;` defines the return value.